# F# Implicit ModuleSuffix not working when using fully qualified name

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

I have an F# project with a file which defines a type and module as follows:

```
module Domain 
  type TodoID = TodoID of int
  module TodoID = let value (TodoID i) = i

  let ti = TodoID 1
  let i1 = TodoID.value ti // Works as expected
```

F#'s compiler automatically adds the suffix "Module" to TodoID, so that the fully qualified name of the unpacking function is `Domain.TodoIDModule.value`, as expected (see [FS-1019](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1019-implicitly-add-the-module-suffix.md)).

When I reference the function from another file, opening the `Domain` module as follows, all is good:

```
module DTO_working
  open Domain

  let ti = TodoID 1
  let i1 = TodoID.value ti // Happiness
```

However, when I have a file in which I don't open the module, instead trying to fully qualify the function, I can't get it to work:

```
module DTO_broken
  let ti = Domain.TodoID 1
  let i1 = Domain.TodoID.value ti // error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'value' is not defined.
  let i2 = Domain.TodoIDModule.value ti // error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'TodoIDModule' is not defined
```

When I hover over the `value` portion of `Domain.TodoID.value` in Visual Studio, it shows the full name correctly as `Domain.TodoIDModule.value`.

When I manually add in the `Module` suffix and type it out everywhere, it works.

What am I missing? Is it possible to reference a function that has an automatic "Module" suffix without opening the module?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Roland

Comment: Hmm it looks like when you use the module name prefix, e.g. `Domain.TodoID`, it always refers to the DU case `TodoID`, not the type `TodoID`, rather than picking one based on the context. That is a bit weird in my opinion and maybe a bug in F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me start off by saying - this should work.

I started with the [F# tests on auto module suffix](https://github.com/dsyme/fsharp/blob/b8c748c69c4fca42d2dc66024388d6e7b69a7971/tests/fsharp/core/longnames/test.fsx#L410):

```
module Ok1

module A =
    let create() = 1
    type Dummy = A | B


type A = 
    member x.P = 1

let works = (typeof<A.Dummy>.FullName.Contains("AModule"))
```

This works fine. It seems to be when a DU case is of the same name.

But there's [a test case that covers this](https://github.com/dsyme/fsharp/blob/b8c748c69c4fca42d2dc66024388d6e7b69a7971/tests/fsharp/core/longnames/test.fsx#L577):

```
module Ok13

type A = A of string

module A = 
    let create() = 1
    type Dummy = A | B
```

But in another file,

```
module Ok13Test

let i1 = Ok13.A.create ()
```

does fail. 
There's also no problem if `TodoId` DU case was refactored to `TodoIDCase`:

```
type TodoID = TodoIDCase of int

module TodoID =
    let public value (TodoIDCase i) = i
```

The problem is not in generating the module suffix, which it does correctly (IL verified), but type inference assigning a higher visibility to the DU case. If you bring down the visibility,

```
type private A = A of string
```

it starts working again. This seems to a problem with the type inference, so it's probably best to refactor the DU case for now and file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've filed the bug report here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8424